# How does quarkus support basic authentication with keycloak as identity provider?

Tags: keycloak, basic-authentication, quarkus

I want to secure a rest service with basic authentication. The credentials should be used to obtain an access token from a keycloak instance for that client and check the allowed roles on the service.

The quarkus [security architecture guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#basic-auth) states that *at least one extension installed that provides a username/password based IdentityProvider* is required. It refers to JPA IdentityProvider and JDBC IdentityProvider, only. But I want to authenticate agains keycloak.

I have successfully setup a web app and a rest service with quarkus-oidc. It authenticates the user and provides access to the rest service via access token.

I also used [properties files](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-properties) with basic authentication successfully.

My keycloak `myclient` setup has `Direct Access Grants Enabled` with `Access Type` set to `confidential`.

My configuration in application.properties:

```
quarkus.oidc.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=myclient
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.http.auth.basic=true
```

Is this a valid combination?

When I debug into HttpAuthenticator constructor the only mechanism found is `OidcAuthenticationMechanism`, I'd expect `BasicAuthenticationMechanism` to be present.